# Woocommerce Related Product by 2 taxonomy

Tags: php, wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to change related product by taxonomy and if taxonomy didnt have enough product, display rest of it from other taxonomy.

I have 2 taxonomy; **`product_tag`** and **`product_cat`**. Sometimes products in **`product_tag`** are not more than 4, so I need to use another taxonomy to fulfill 4 product in related product.

So I need 4 related product, If product_tag has all of them so nothing, if not use product_cat to complete 4 product.

Any help would be greatefull.

```
<?php
    // get the custom post type's taxonomy terms
    $related_category = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids') );
    $related_tag = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag', array('fields' => 'ids') );
    // arguments
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 4, // you may edit this number
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $related_tag
        )
    ),
    'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
    );
    $related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
    // loop over query
    if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
    while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="related_item">
      <div class="Related_image">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
      </div>
        <div class="Related_title">
          <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><h2>

        </div>
      </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

Comment: Related products sections on products detail page in WooCommerce by default pulls products from your store that share the same tags or categories as the current product. Check reference link: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/related-products-up-sells-and-cross-sells/

Comment: I know. But I want show 5 related product based on tag, then category. I mean If I have 3 product in same tag, display 2 other product from product category.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did it. so if this code is wrong or could be simplified just correct it.
I want 5 product result. So all of it should be from **`product_tag`** if it is available. if not use **`product_cat`**. so I combined  2 arg here:

```
<?php
        // get the custom post type's taxonomy terms
        $related_tag = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag', array('fields' => 'ids'));
        $related_cat = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'ids'));


        // arguments 1
        $args1 = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => '',

        'tax_query' => array(

            array(

                'taxonomy'     => 'product_tag',
                'field'        => 'id',
                'terms'        =>  $related_tag,
            ),

        ),
        'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
         );
        // arguments 2
        $args2 = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby' => 'rand',

        'tax_query' => array(

            array(

                'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
                'field'        => 'id',
                'terms'        =>  $related_cat,
            ),

        ),
        'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),

        );

        $related_items1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );
        $related_items2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
        $related_items = new WP_Query();
        $related_items->posts = array_merge( $related_items1->posts, $related_items2->posts );

        $related_items3->post_count=5 - $related_items1->post_count;

        $related_items->post_count = $related_items1->post_count + $related_items3->post_count;


        // loop over query
        if ($related_items->have_posts()) :
        while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="related_item">
          <div class="Related_image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
          </div>
            <div class="Related_title">
              <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><h2>

            </div>
          </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        endif;
        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```